# Python loop ending but then ends but then repeats for no reason

Tags: python

I am making a program for the backend of a profiling system for my exam practice. I have the username and passwords stored in a .txt file. It says it is valid when I enter the password and goes to the next part of the program but then loops back and asks for the details again???

Here is my code where I think the problem is:

```
def Login(): #Login function
    f = open('login.txt','r')
    username = f.readline().strip() 
    password = f.readline().strip()

    usernameLog = input('Please enter your username: ')

    validuser = False
    while validuser == False:
        if usernameLog == username:
            print('Username accepted')

            time.sleep(1)

            userpassLog = input('Please enter a password: ')

            if userpassLog == password:
                print('Successfully logged in')

                time.sleep(0.5)
                Options()
                validuser = True
            else:
                print('Please enter a valid password')
            validuser = False
        else:
            print('Invalid username please re-enter it.')
            validuser = False
            Login()
    f.close()
```

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: There is always a reason for everything. Check your loop condition.

Comment: I guess you have another call to `Login()` somewhere else in the program.

Comment: Are you sure that the `validuser=False` in the first `else` block is nested correctly? Shouldn't it be in the else block and not outside after the `if ... else` is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to answer your question: under your `else` condition for a wrong password (under `print('Please enter a valid password')`), you have a non-indented `validuser = False`. So what happens is that the `validuser = True` that you set a bit earlier when the password was good is replaced instantly by a `validuser = False`. Simply indenting that line to put it within your `else` condition fixes your code :)

Now, talking optimisation/best practice... In your code you are using both an infinite loop conditional on a variable which is an *iterative* approach, and a call to your function within your function which is a *recursive* approach, which is not in my opinion a really good choice... Or at least not for the same level of the loop!

If you wanted to go fully iterative, then you would simply need to replace your `Login()` towards the end by

```
usernameLog = input('Please enter your username: ')
```

Or, if you want to have both a recursive call and an iterative loop, you could loop only over the password:

```
def Login():
    f = open('login.txt','r')
    username = f.readline().strip() 
    password = f.readline().strip()

    usernameLog = input('Please enter your username: ')

    if usernameLog == username:
        print('Username accepted')

        time.sleep(1)

        validpassword = False
        while validpassword == False:
            userpassLog = input('Please enter a password: ')
            if userpassLog == password:
                print('Successfully logged in')

                time.sleep(0.5)
                Options()
                validpassword = True
            else:
                print('Please enter a valid password')
                validpassword = False
    else:
        print('Invalid username please re-enter it.')
        Login()
    f.close()
```

To be honest, re-opening the same file every time you enter a wrong username seems a bit of a waste of time, so I'd recommend using the iterative-only version if that's good with your assignment...

Answer (score 0):

breaking solved the issue:

```
while validuser == False:
    if usernameLog == username:
        print('Username accepted')

        time.sleep(1)

        userpassLog = input('Please enter a password: ')



        if userpassLog == password:
            validuser = True
            print('Successfully logged in')


            time.sleep(0.5)
            Options()
            break
```

Comment: Doing that is a bit of a hard solution to fix your code I think... Works fine, sure, but not as elegant ;)